# Cannot package electron js app built on top of a react web app

Tags: reactjs, electron, parceljs

I'm trying to package and distribute my electron js desktop application, built on top of a react web application using **parcel** as a bundler.

To do this, i'm using the following cmds:

`npm run build` to build the web app, and then `npm run package` to create the executable file.

The problem is that the desktop app is created but the react part is not rendering, getting this error:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

Tried logging the path of index.html and it seems all good, the problem is within the index.js part!

here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "gympro-administration",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "electron/electron.js",
  "homepage": "./",
  "source": "public/index.html",
  "targets": {
    "main": false
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "concurrently  \"cross-env BROWSER=none PORT=3000 parcel\" \"wait-on http://localhost:3000 && electron .",
    "electron-dev": "electron .",
    "build": "parcel build",
    "serve": "yarn build && firebase emulators:start --only hosting:gymproadmin",
    "shell": "yarn build && firebase functions:shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only hosting:gymproadmin",
    "logs": "firebase hosting:log",
    "watch": "parcel watch",
    "stats": "parcel build --reporter @parcel/reporter-bundle-analyzer",
    "buddy": "parcel build --reporter @parcel/reporter-bundle-buddy",
    "dev": "npm start",
    "package": "electron-builder"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    ....
  },
  "dependencies": {
    .....
  }
}
```

This is my electron main entry (electron.js):

```
const { app, ipcMain } = require("electron");
const { createWindow } = require("./window.js");
const ipcDispatcher = require("./ipc/ipcDispatcher.js");
const handlers = require("./ipc/handlerRegistry.js");

let mainWindow;
app.whenReady().then(() => {
  mainWindow = createWindow();

  Object.keys(handlers).forEach((channel) => {
    ipcMain.handle(channel, (e, data) => {
      return ipcDispatcher.dispatch(channel, data);
    });
  });
});

app.on("window-all-closed", () => {
  if (process.platform !== "darwin") {
    app.quit();
  }
});

app.on("activate", () => {
  if (mainWindow === null) {
    createWindow();
  }
});
```

And this is my window.js:

```
const { BrowserWindow } = require("electron");
const initializeDatabase = require("../electron/db/database.js");

const path = require("path");
let mainWindow;

function createWindow() {
  // Initialize the database
  initializeDatabase();

  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      contextIsolation: false,
      preload: path.resolve(__dirname, "./db/preload.js"),
    },
  });

/*   const distPath = path.resolve(__dirname, "..", "dist");
  const filePath = path.join(distPath, "index.html");
  mainWindow.loadURL("http://localhost:3000"); */
const distPath = path.resolve(__dirname, "..", "dist");
const filePath = path.join(distPath, "index.html");
mainWindow.loadFile(filePath);
//mainWindow.loadURL("http://localhost:3000");

  mainWindow.on("closed", () => (mainWindow = null));
  return mainWindow;
}

module.exports = {
  createWindow,
};
```

Please note that when I run it using `mainWindow.loadURL("http://localhost:3000")` it works all good and the screens are rendered. But once I point it towards the index.html (under dist) it gives the same error! And please note that when I point it towards index.html under public folder it gives this error: `Unexpected token: '<'` (probably not reading the jsx code).

EDIT:
index.html (under dist):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head><link rel="stylesheet" href="/index.4746b4dd.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/react-leaflet-markercluster/dist/styles.min.css">
    <title>GymPro</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="/index.975ef6c8.js" defer=""></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I appreciate your help!

Comment: Does it throw a file name and line number where the error occurred? The path in you index.html for the index.js is not correctly set. Can you also post the <script> tag in you index.html.

Comment: Of course, the file exists in my code but when I try to ctrl click it from index.html it says that the file is not found, I will edit my post to add index.html code.

Comment: Can you try by removing the first / in the path. `<script src="index.975ef6c8.js" defer=""></script>`

Comment: I got this error: [1] (node:25804) electron: Failed to load URL: file:///C:/ with error: ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Comment: OK, try using the full path of the file, just for the moment. E.g. if you're on Windows it might be file:///C:/..../index.j 975ef6c8.js

Comment: Also, check where `path.join(__dirname, './dcp-electron/index.html')` is implemented, make sure to have . (dot) there

Comment: For your second comment, it is already all good! But for the first one, I tried setting the path as follows:     <script src="file:///C:/Users/fedy_/OneDrive/Bureau/GymProDesktop/gym-pro-admin/dist/index.975ef6c8.js" defer=""></script> 
I got this error: Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/ (from chromewebdata)
and even when I remove file:/// I get the same error
I added webSecurity: false in window.js and the error disappeared but I got a blank screen.
Please note that the content shows for a second then strangely disappears and stays as a blank screen now

Comment: Please share your electron-builder config.

Comment: I didn't really get it, I just installed electron-builder and used it as follows:     "package": "electron-builder"